# Apache access to example.com/app from different root directory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, server

For now, I have following directories:
[image: Sample directory structure]

WordPress directory is connected with *example.com* domain. I would like to access my Zend app by *example.com/app* URL, but it is in separated directory. I tried to add rewrite rule in htaccess file in WordPress directory, but server responds me with 400 error. I tried that without success:

```
RewriteRule ^app/(.*)$ ../zend_app/$1
```

And now I am not sure what to do. I think about some php file to include something from *zend_app* folder or to create symlink inside WordPress directory pointing to *zend_app* folder. What solution is better? Maybe there is another solution? I am using shared hosting, so possibilities are limited.

EDIT:
Here is my whole htaccess file from WordPress:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^app/(.*)$ zend_app/$1 [L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: If you use `example.com/zend_app/index.php` does it work?

Comment: No, because *zend_app* is in different folder than *wordpress*.

Comment: Well that alone shouldn't matter. Are you getting a `400` error not a `404` error?

Comment: With RewriteRule I am getting 400 error

Comment: If the `zend_app` directory is a child of `public_html` remove the `../` in your rewrite rule. And since you are adding that to an existing Wordpress `.htaccess` you'll want it to be at the top and add `[L]` to the rule so nothing else gets processed. `RewriteRule ^app/(.*)$ zend_app/$1 [L]`

Comment: Now I have 404 error from WordPress

Comment: Please edit your question and include the contents of your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: I edited my question with htaccess file.